# Reduce table scope using JOIN in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 files stored in S3:

1. movies: ~10 mils records
2. ratings: ~1 mils records

I would like to read and store the output as parquet as below:

1. movies: only movies that available in ratings files.
2. ratings: load everything.

Should I use temp table with SQL query below to achieve this? But I have doubt about the performance here.

If there is anything can be done to improve? What shoud I do?

Thanks.

```
title.createOrReplaceTempView("TMPtitles")
rating.createOrReplaceTempView("TMPratings")

title_rating = spark.sql("""
        SELECT titles.movie_id, titles.movie_type, titles.primary_title, titles.original_title, titles.is_adult, titles.start_year,
            titles.end_year, titles.runtime_minutes, titles.genres
        FROM TMPtitles titles
        WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TMPratings ratings WHERE titles.movie_id = ratings.movie_id)
        """)
```

Comment: are you getting the desired results with your query? what do you mean by *"ratings: load everything"* -- all movie_id records from that table should be available in your output?

Comment: Yes you are correct. Output of movies should limited by movie_id in ratings. I'm running that query in my local (docker) but it's taking so long and can't complete after 30 mins, so i stopped  it.

Comment: you're better off doing an inner join which spark can optimize internally in spark plan. from my experience, `where exists` does not work well with spark plan and ends up (at least in my cases) doing a nested cartesian merge

Answer (score 1):

You better do a join rather than WHERE EXISTS, you can also broadcast ratings table which will improve performance.

```
SELECT /*+ BROADCASTJOIN(TMPratings) */ * 
FROM TMPtitles JOIN TMPratings
ON TMPtitles.movie_id = TMPratings.movie_id
```

Comment: @Hana I updated my answer I made a mistake with the BROADCASTJOIN, it should be good now.